# Is IClientMessageInspector available for WP7 development

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-7

I have some advanced WCF client work I would like to do with Windows Phone. Is IClientMessageInspector available?  I don't see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[IClientMessageInspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iclientmessageinspector%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) is in Silverlight 4 but Windows Phone 7 is based on Silverlight 3. As such it's not available on the phone.

Some functionlity form Silverlight 4 has been back ported to the phone but not this.